# How to preview table borders in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2010

I'm pretty positive I was able to *preview* table borders in MS Word. E.g. table borders were visible on screen, but not printed on paper. I would like to get that behaviour back, but cannot find such option.

To reiterate: I want my table borders to be visible on-screen only, I know how to change table borders' width etc., but these changes are reflected on paper too...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can enable `View Gridlines` under **Table Tools > Layout** when a table is focused. When no border is set, Word will draw a light-blue, dashed line in its place.

[image: view gridlines]

---

### Demonstration:

- With borders:

  [image: with]
- Without borders:

  [image: without]
- What is printed:

  [image: blank]

---

### Alternatively,

Word will draw table gridlines if you have `Show text boundaries` enabled under **File > Options > Advanced > Show document content**. The `View Gridlines` option above only applies to tables while this applies to the entire document. Also, the lines are dotted instead of dashed.

[image: options]

[image: boundaries]

Answer (score 0):

Use the table Tools/Design tab/Borders drop down list.  Select All Borders

Comment: this will change the format for that table, not preview how the table looks like